# How can I store login username as a variable using Meteor?

Tags: meteor

How can I make a variable for the current user's username as they log in to create a database document for them to store their info?

Comment: meteor already manages this.  See http://docs.meteor.com/#accounts_api

Answer (score 1):

You need to setup a custom function to configure user creation in server side, see [Accounts.onCreateUser on docs.meteor.com](http://docs.meteor.com/#accounts_oncreateuser)

In this function you can initialize your user database document, either in user.field or user.profile.field.
The username is automatically stored in user.username, you do not need to create it.

Then to modify the user record client side, simply call a server method that will update the Meteor.users collection, ie

server/users.js

```
Meteor.methods({
    updateUser:function(fields){
        if(!this.userId){
            // error : no user logged in
        }
        check(fields,{/* fields verification */});
        Meteor.users.update(this.userId,{
            $set:fields
        });
    }
});
```

client/main.js

```
Meteor.call("updateUser",{
    "username":"foo",
    "profile.bar":"bar"
});
```

Note that Meteor built-in user accounts greatly simplify all this process : it is well documented so I encourage you re-read that particular section in the docs.